# Why can't I find a Control ID in my Resource file in ATL?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, atl

Since I need to do some checks depending on which control is on focus in my app, I am getting the focused control ID like this:

```
HWND controlOnFocus = ::GetFocus();
int controlID = ::GetDlgCtrlID(controlOnFocus);
```

I am getting consistent IDs, but I can't find them in the resource file!
Can I rely on the IDs I am getting or what?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet of code gets the control identifier from whichever window has the current focus. Your application is likely to include lots of windows that you haven't created yourself, such as common dialogue boxes, and the IDs for those won't be in your resource file. Also, not all windows have useful control IDs; For instance, static text controls usually have ID_STATIC (-1?).

Comment: I am executing the snippet on a right-click event handler (it's actually a message handler with signature `UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL&` so I can't get the raising control ID) to check from which control is coming - right-click on the same controls gets me same IDs. How should I interpret this?

Comment: Forgot to add My controls are dynamically generated - can I rely on the ID if don't change anything else?

Comment: First, I'd recommend firing up SpyXX to check what windows there really are around your control. Secondly, note that if you right-clicking on a control doesn't set the focus. Instead, call WindowFromPoint to find out which window was under the pointer.

Comment: If you create a window with an ID, you can rely on the window having that ID for its lifetime. The ID actually gets stored in a window-specific area (in the OS, rather than in ATL). See ::GetWindowLong( hWnd, GWL_ID );